# select rows in a specific range in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select rows in a specific range of a column and this column has numeric random values but it returns greater values from given range

| SNO | Name | R_NO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tws | 20 |
| 2 | Twa | 12 |
| 3 | Twf | 202 |
| 4 | Tww | 25 |
| 5 | Twz | 205 |
| 6 | Tsz | 22 |

so far i have tried following

```sql
select * from table where R_NO between '20' AND '25'

select * from table where R_NO >= '20' AND R_NO <= '25'

select * from table where R_NO > '20' AND R_NO < '25'
```

but they all return values exceeding actual given range

e.g it will return

| SNO | Name | R_NO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tws | 20 |
| 3 | Twf | 202 |
| 4 | Tww | 25 |
| 5 | Twz | 205 |
| 6 | Tsz | 22 |

my actual range is 1001 to 1500
and im getting value like

```
1001, 100111100, 100297, 100273, 1005F, 100901, 101-720088 and more
```

but the result must be between 1001 to 1500.
please let me know whats the problem with my query

Comment: Is the `R_NO` column _numeric_, or is it text?  If you are trying to do a numerical range comparison against it, this would imply that `R_NO` should probably be numeric, and not text.

Comment: Remove the quotes from around your numbers. Like you wrote it, the database is converting R_NO to text and comparing it to what you give, and in that case, '100000' is lower than '15'.

Comment: NO, they are not exact numeric as column contains values like 101-52356 @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @gsalem when i remove quotes oracle SQL plus throws an error of ora 01722 invalid number
An ORA-01722 error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a character string into a number, and the string cannot be converted into a number.

Comment: @Wanda `101-52356` cannot be a numeric value, it is text of some sort.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i just want 1001 to 1500 and skipping all other even if it is text, string or something else.
1001 to 1500 range in numbers it should to 500 rows only

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings that look like numbers rather than number.

When you perform a string comparison, it compares the individual characters in sequence (depending on the NLS settings, that could be looking at the ASCII values of the characters or there could be more complicated national character set specific rules).

When you perform a numeric comparison, it compares the entire number values.

If you do:

```sql
select * from table where R_NO between 'CA' AND 'CF'
```

Then the values `'CA'`, `'CAE'` and `'CF'` are all considered to be in the range. You can get exactly the same result substituting `A` for `0`, `C` for `2` and `F` for `5` to get your data. So the strings `'20'`, `'205'` and `'25'` will all be `BETWEEN '20' and '25'`.

If you are using Oracle 12 or later, you can convert the value to a number and compare that way using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  TO_NUMBER(R_NO DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR)
       BETWEEN 20 AND 25
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (SNO, Name, R_NO) AS
SELECT 1, 'Tws', '20'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Twa', '12'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Twf', '202' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Tww', '25'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Twz', '205' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Tsz', '22'  FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SNO | NAME | R_NO |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Tws | 20 |
> | 4 | Tww | 25 |
> | 6 | Tsz | 22 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=cbe849d88aaa4f3a79833c6e972523e0)*

Comment: yes, you are awesome